# Why is it not possible to define property observers for computed propertys?

Tags: swift

I am currently playing around with swift and there is one thing i don't understand.

Lets take a look at the following ***non compiling code snippet***

```
class A {
    var test : String  {
        get {
            return "foo"
        }

        set {
            self.test = newValue
        }

        willSet {

        }

        didSet {

        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the Compiler is complaining. So i am not able to implement all of them: get and set, didSet and willSet. I thought that observing computed properties is maybe not possible.

So i played around a little bit more and then i discovered that subclasses can override the property observers of computed propertys.
What the hack? ***This doesnt makes sense to me***

```
import UIKit

class A {
    var test : String  {
        get {
            return "name"
        }

        set {
            self.test = newValue
        }
    }
}

class B : A {
    override var test : String {
        willSet {

        }

        didSet {

        }
    }
}
```

***Why i am not able to add property observers in the first code snippet but i am able to overwrite these observers inside a subclass?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code, you don't *need* observers, because you already are writing the code that sets the property (`set`). Thus, if you want to do something before/after the property gets set, you can just do it right there in the setter handler (`set`):

```
class A {
    var test : String  {
        get {
            return "foo"
        }
        set {
            // will set
            self.test = newValue
            // did set
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, by a kind of Occam's Razor principle, it would be redundant and unnecessary to have separate setter observers: you *are* the setter, so there is no need to observe yourself.

In your subclass override, on the other hand, where you didn't supply a whole new computed property, the setting is going on behind your back, as it were, so as compensation you are allowed to inject set observation into the process.

Comment: I make this same observation in a Tip at the end of my book's section on setter observers, here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_setter_observers

Comment: Alright, if i think a little bit longer about this it totally makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> “You don’t need to define property observers for non-overridden computed properties, because you can observe and respond to changes to their value in the computed property’s setter.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1).” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/cn/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?l=en&mt=11